# Capturing hyperlinks conditionally in regex captures too much

Tags: regex, jscript

I'm attempting to replace specific hyperlinks in text with the following expression:

```
<a .*?href=(['"]?).*?\/?download.aspx\?myid=\{?([0-9a-f]{8}-?[0-9a-f]{4}-?[0-9a-f]{4}-?[0-9a-f]{4}-?[0-9a-f]{12})\}?\1.*?>(.*?)<\/a>
```

Example text:

```html
<a clicktracking=off href="https://www.test.com/1.pdf">test</a><br />Test<br />Test</div><br><div>&nbsp;</div><br><div><a clicktracking=off href="download.aspx?myID=11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555">Teet.docx</a></div>
```

My issues is that it's capturing everything between the first `<a` and the last `</a>` when I want it to capture only `<a clicktracking=off href="download.aspx?myID=11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555">Teet.docx</a>` (along with any other links that match that format).

I've tried putting in `[^>]` some different spots to get it to 'break out' out of the match early but had no luck. I've also tried inserting a newline after each `</a>` and that lets it work but it's not desirable to alter text beyond the link that I want to replace.

Regex101 Example:
https://regex101.com/r/BjpO1d/1

Unsure if it matters but I'm using "JScript".

Comment: Correct. Exclude matching `<a` with space or `</a>` and you will get it, replace the first two `.*?` with `(?:(?!<\/?a[\s>]).)*?`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BjpO1d/2). JScript regex is based on very early implementation of ECMAScript, but I think lookaheads are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "exclude" `a` tag from matching with `.*?`:

```
<a\s(?:(?!<\/?a[\s>]).)*?href=(['"]?)(?:(?!<\/?a[\s>]).)*?download\.aspx\?myid=\{?([0-9a-f]{8}-?[0-9a-f]{4}-?[0-9a-f]{4}-?[0-9a-f]{4}-?[0-9a-f]{12})\}?\1.*?>(.*?)<\/a>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BjpO1d/3).

See `(?:(?!<\/?a[\s>]).)*?` which means

- `(?:`  - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?!<\/?a[\s>]).` - any one char other than line break chars that is not the starting point for the `<\/?a[\s>]` pattern: `<`, an optional `/`, `a`, a whitespace or `>`
- `)*?` - end of the group, zero or more repetition, as few as possible.